Exam class: how can I align parts name with questions



I'm making test in exam class and I'd like to change parts name for example instead of
'(a)' I want 'Questions 1.1.', so that the first number is number of question and second number is part number. The problem is the part name is move to left. The code is:
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
        %% Q Format
        %% ----------------------------------------------
            \qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} (0--\thepoints) \hfill} 
        \bonusqformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} \hfill} 
            
            \renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
            }
            \pointname{}
            
            \renewcommand\partlabel{\textbf{Question \thequestion.\arabic{partno}.}}
        %% -----------------------------------------------
        
        %% Point Format
        %% ----------------------------------------------
            \pointformat{(0--\thepoints)}
            \bonuspointformat{(0--\thepoints)}
        %% -----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \gradetable[h][questions]
    \end{center}
\begin{questions}
\question[2] 'Instruction'

\bonusquestion
'Instructions'
    \begin{parts}
        \part[3] Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.
        \part[2] \lipsum[1]
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}

with this code i get:

so you can see that only the part number '2.1.' is align to 'Question 2.'. How can I align all part name with number 'Question 2.1.' to question name 'Question 2.'?
2.
Now I move all part label and it's align to questions, but the text is moved too. I'd like to have like in questions 'Questions no. (points) \hfill' and the text is from the next line and is also aligned to part and question label.
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
        %% Q Format
        %% ----------------------------------------------
            \qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} (0--\thepoints) \hfill} 
            \bonusqformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} \hfill} 
            
            \renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
            }
            \pointname{}
            
            \renewcommand\partlabel{\textbf{Question \thequestion.\arabic{partno}.}}
            
            \renewcommand{\partshook}{
            
            \advance\leftmargin by -\labelwidth           \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\partlabel}           \advance\leftmargin by \labelwidth
            }

        %% -----------------------------------------------
        
        %% Point Format
        %% ----------------------------------------------
            \pointformat{(0--\thepoints)}
            \bonuspointformat{(0--\thepoints)}
        %% -----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \gradetable[h][questions]
    \end{center}
\begin{questions}
\question[2] 'Instruction'

\bonusquestion
'Instructions'
    \begin{parts}
        \part[3] Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.
        \part[2] \lipsum[1]
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}

and I got this:

but I'd like something like this:


If you wnat the parts left aligned with hte quewstions, you can use \renewcommand{\partshook}{\advance\leftmargin by -\labelwidth           \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\partlabel}           \advance\leftmargin by \labelwidth}

But now also the instruction which have more than 1 line is move right

In that case, make \partshook the same as \questionshook, except also add \settowidth{\itemindent}{\partlabel}.  There is a diagrapm on page 3 of the enumitem manual which shows all the distances used.

I don't quite understand how to do it, I added a second point to the question, in which I presented what I mean

The only way I have found to not start the question immediately after the points was to fill the remaining space.
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
        %% Q Format
        %% ----------------------------------------------
            \qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} (0--\thepoints) \hfill} 
            \bonusqformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} \hfill} 
            
            \renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
            }
            \pointname{}
            
            \renewcommand\partlabel{\textbf{Question \thequestion.\arabic{partno}.}}
            \renewcommand{\partshook}{%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
            \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\partlabel}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{\dimexpr \labelwidth+\labelsep}%
            }
            
        %% -----------------------------------------------
        
        %% Point Format
        %% ----------------------------------------------
            \pointformat{\makebox[\dimexpr \textwidth-\itemindent][l]{(0--\thepoints)}}
            \bonuspointformat{\makebox[\dimexpr \textwidth-\itemindent][l]{(0--\thepoints)}}
        %% -----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \gradetable[h][questions]
    \end{center}
\begin{questions}
\question[2] 'Instruction'

\bonusquestion
'Instructions'
    \begin{parts}
        \part[3] Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.
        \part[2] \lipsum[1]
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}


Yeeeass, thats exactly what I needed, and once again thank you for your help!
